# Handing back my mod diamond

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

To Josh, Stack Team, and Community,

As per my Skype conversation with Josh this evening, I am giving immediate notice of my resignation as a Stack Overflow moderator.

It's been a hell of a ride since I joined Stack Overflow back in 2008(?) as user 419 - I still remember emailing Jeff directly and asking for a beta account and the excitement about being accepted - and then having the community trust me as a moderator. However I'm no longer able to perform this role adequately due to personal circumstances.

I wish all the SO team and mods the best of luck for the future. I will continue to evangelise Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange sites when and wherever I have the opportunity.

I have truly enjoyed working with the other SO mods, in particular Bill, Tim, Rob, Will, Michael, Nicholas and George. It has been an honour working with you guys and you've taught me so many things about how to engage with such a diverse community like Stack Overflow.

ChrisF - I have no idea how you manage to mod so many sites :)

Josh (Shog) - thanks for teaching me many of the subtle nuances when dealing with difficult community situations - trolls, crazy users, rage quitters, etc. We may not have agreed back in the early days of SO, but by god what a damn fine community manager you've become. I think all of the SE mods would agree that you've taught us a thing or two about keeping our community held together.

To the rest of the SO mod team, I never really got to know you as well but I'm sure you'll continue to do a bloody fine job. Keep up the good work and never be afraid to ask for help from the old guard.

To the rest of the community, I thank you all for the opportunity to become a guiding hand in "making the internet a better place" as a Stack Overflow moderator. Let's keep making Stack Overflow a first class programmer's Q&A site.

All the best,
Kev

Comment: You did a great job.

Comment: Not sure if to up or downvote: noooo! come back Kev! :-P (thanks for all the hard work, you did a great job!)

Comment: Happy trails! Sorry I never got to 'know' you well! And thanks for being a part of keeping this an awesome site!

Comment: "... in particular [list of all other mods]."

Comment: Thanks for everything! And know that you were always my favourite moderator, or somewhere close anyways. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your service.  You guys do an amazing job keeping the site clean.  Now, to the bullpen!

Comment: Nooooooo! Thanks for all you've done :D you have been an amazing mod. Good luck with whatever you are going on to do, you will be missed :)

Comment: Thanks folks for the kind words. Feel free to edit if the grammar or tags suck, it wouldn't be SO if someone didn't have a tinker here and there :)

Comment: @Kev: I was tempted to remove the "All the best, Kev" for "Removed signature." ;P

Comment: @animuson I see you saw what I deliberately did there :)

Comment: **Upvote because you did a great job, not because you are leaving.**

Comment: Will you still be active?

Comment: This is certainly a surprise and I'm sorry to see you go.

Comment: I still think it would be nice if ex-mods would get a white diamond or something to indicate their former modship: Kev ◊ or to show that we still love you Kev ♥

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the time you put in as a moderator and as a user making Stack Overflow better.

Comment: Think you're the first to ever put such announcement - at least as far as I know - thanks for letting us all know and use the free time you'll now have wisely! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: wisely=get more SO rep, no? :P

Comment: Also, first time I've _ever_ seen anyone call Shog9 Josh. Hm.

Comment: @Manishearth: That will totally be the next Meta meme...

Comment: @jadarnel27, there are two schools of thought whether to include a comma before the _and_ (or _or_) in a list of more than two things. So it's not an _error_ to omit it (though I include it, myself).

Comment: Can he keep the diamond as a momento for being excellent?

Comment: @msh210 Oh yes, I'm familiar with the Oxford comma debate.  I was mainly fixing "quitters" =)  I would never edit just to add the comma.  But, if I'm really editing something else, I will usually add the comma (because I like it).

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I was going to bring up the Oxford comma but to be honest I'm pretty agnostic about it myself...and yes "quitters"...oops, but in my defence I had consumed a couple of litres of Polish beer when I wrote that :)

Comment: @Undo Thanks matey, I'll still be participating as a normal user when time permits.

Comment: @Kev Completely understandable under the circumstances =)  I was certainly not trying to be critical, I was just goofing on your comment requesting edits, and I noticed the one typo.

Comment: It's been an honor to work with you, however short a duration that was.

Comment: We all know @Kev is only really making this post for the extra reputation upticks, otherwise he'd have checked the community wiki box.  :-)  It is nice to observe a dignified resignation. Good luck, in your future endeavors, sir!

Answer (score 61):

I, along with much of Meta, was surprised to find that you are leaving.

### Thank you.

You have been a fine mod - way better than I could be.

You worked out many of the problems that Stack Overflow had in the early days.

#### Thank you for everything,

### Meta

Comment: "way better than I could be", eh?

Answer (score 46):

Kev, thank you. For the kind words, and most of all for all the work you've put in over the years to keep Stack Overflow running smoothly.

As we discussed yesterday and I've now [announced here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171547/spring-2013-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results), minitech will be stepping up to take your place on the site.

From all of us here at SE, please accept our heartfelt appreciation and best wishes for you in the future.

Regards,  
-shog9

Comment: :O A signature! Must. Restrain. Edit. Habit.

Answer (score 27):

I'm deeply honored that you mentioned me.

I remember when I first came on board, and I was a bit raw, in *all* respects.  You had the patience to deal with me and I became the better mod for it.

You've had an impact on more than just the site, but on those who will continue to moderate it, as those things that I've learned from you I will try and pass on down to others.

I wish you well in all that you do, and hope we'll see you around here from time to time.

And we do have to have that a beer at some point, given our mutual rabid fondness for it.

Comment: Count me in on beer - We've got to find a way to get this bloke to NYC for beer and burgers, it's a moral imperative.